# applescript times out when launching terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, appleevents

I have a script wherein I need to run an executable from a terminal

the script is as below

```
    tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set run_cmd to "sudo <path to my executable>"
    do script run_cmd
    end tell
```

but this times out with the error message

```
error "Terminal got an error: AppleEvent timed out." number -1712
```

I even tried using a timeout like

with timeout of 5000 seconds

```
   tell application "Terminal"
        activate
         with timeout of 5000 seconds
        set run_cmd to "sudo <path to my executable>"
        do script run_cmd
         end timeout
        end tell
```

but no luck it still times out...

This behaviour is observed sometimes , not always. I'm using El Capitan Mac OS.

I got a chance to test on Sierra and High Sierra and it works alright there.

Any idea, how can we solve this issue ?

**Note: If I open a terminal before running this script, then it executes without any problems.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't utilize the [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command from within your AppleScript instead of your current `tell application "Terminal" ... end tell` block? For instance, why not replace all your code with  `do shell script "sudo <path to my executable>"`

Comment: Tried it but got this error sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Answer (score 1):

How about trying something like this...

```
tell application "Terminal" to launch
repeat while application "Terminal" is not running
    delay 0.2
end repeat
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set run_cmd to "sudo <path to my executable>"
    do script run_cmd
end tell
```

Comment: Worked for a few runs and sometimes didn't.  Maybe its just the Mac OS acting weird.